# VMware disk file is too large, how to reduce the size of it

Tags: macos, vmware

Im using VMware and my guest OS is mac OS X 10.7.5. My host OS is windows 7

Now the vmdk file ( the virtual hard disk file) is almost 120GB. In my windows, the total size of the partition is 120GB, where the virtual OS located.

I cannot use my virtual Mac any more because of the storge. Is there any way to reduce the size of the virtual machine. I have already cleaned my Mac and deleted some stuff inside Mac, but it seems no decline from my windows, still red alert on that partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a fixed size virtual disk you can not shrink it unless you convert it to a dynamic size. The only way to do that is to copy all the data into a new dynamic sized disk with 

`VBoxManage clonehd [old-VDI] [new-VDI] --variant Standard`

[Command from here](http://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/howto-convert-vdis-between-fixed-sized-and-dynamic-in-virtualbox/)

Just note you'll need the space to store two copies of the disk so this might not work without more storage space

If it's dynamicly sized you need to remove files in the virtual OS to shrink it other wise there's no way to shrink it.

Comment: It is possible to shrink dynamic disk with MacOS X. Run your VM, go `Applications` -> `Utilities` -> `Disk Utility` -> choose your partition in the list -> `Erase` tab -> `Erase Free Space` button -> choose fastest method and run. After that shutdown VM. Go to VM options in VMWare Player, find `Hardware` -> `Hard Disk` -> `Utilities` -> `Compact`. Enjoy!